# Send/sync variable/text over LAN in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat, lan

OK, I wanted to make an python application that allows me to send a message over LAN.

Here's the code that "works" "locally" (imagine that I'm forming 2 of my fingers to make an " on those 2 words)

```
username = input("username: ")

run = 1

while run == 1:
    message = input(username + ": ")
    if message == "exit":
        print(username + " left")
        run = 0
    else:
        print(username + ": " + message)
```

My question how do I send the variable "message" over LAN?

I wan't it to send the variable **message** over LAN to another PC and print it on it and the other way around.

Comment: OK, try again; this time, **ask a question**. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, for example.

Comment: OK, I'l edit, wait a sec.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Read it now.

Comment: Nope, no good. Please use the information in the Help Center; this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: I don't understand, what do I do wrong?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is this good enough for you?

Comment: No, sorry. *"how do I..."* questions are a bad fit for SO. Follow e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/3001761 to write a better question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have said yes to all those questions and read the hole d**n thing.

Comment: The code you have posted is **completely irrelevant**; it is trivial and makes no attempt to send `message` anywhere. If you have done any research on sending messages over LAN, there is **no evidence** of it in the question. It is also badly written, although I appreciate that English may not be your first language. Again, *this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service*. I see no point in spending any longer on this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, no need to be so harsh, why didn't you say that from the begining? I'l remove the post if that makes you feel any better.

Comment: He is not harsh. He is trying to explain to you how SO works and instead of getting angry with him you might want to thank him instead, because he is right

Comment: @TimCastelijns He has at least helped me formulate questions better. I'l keep these things in mind for next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several files that may help you with developing a messaging system for your LAN.

---

**Simple_Server.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import socket, select

def main():
    a = [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)]     # socket array
    a[0].bind(('', 8989))
    a[0].listen(5)
    while True:
        for b in select.select(a, [], [])[0]:                   # ready socket
            if b is a[0]:
                a.append(b.accept()[0])
            else:
                try:
                    c = b.recv(1 << 12)                         # sent message
                except socket.error:
                    b.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                    b.close()
                    a.remove(b)
                else:
                    for d in (d for d in a[1:] if d is not b):  # message sink
                        d.sendall(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**MultichatClient.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from safetkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *
import socket
import sys

class MultichatClient(Frame):

    after_handle = None

    def __init__(self, master, remote_host):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.message_area = ScrolledText(self, width=81, height=21,
                                         wrap=WORD, state=DISABLED)
        self.message_area.grid(sticky=NSEW, columnspan=2)
        self.send_area = Entry(self)
        self.send_area.bind('<Return>', self.keyPressed)
        self.send_area.grid(sticky=EW)
        b = Button(self, text='Send', command=self.mouseClicked)
        b.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.send_area.focus_set()
        try:
            self.remote = socket.create_connection((remote_host, 8989))
        except socket.gaierror:
            print('Could not find host {}.'.format(remote_host))
        except socket.error:
            print('Could not connect to host {}.'.format(remote_host))
        else:
            self.remote.setblocking(False)
            self.after_handle = self.after_idle(self.dataready)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    @classmethod
    def main(cls, args):
        root = Tk()
        root.title('MultichatClient version 1.0')
        m = cls(root, args[0])
        m.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.mainloop()
        return 1

    def dataready(self):
        try:
            s = self.remote.recv(1 << 12).decode()
        except socket.error:
            pass
        else:
            self.message_area['state'] = NORMAL
            self.message_area.insert(END, s)
            self.message_area['state'] = DISABLED
            self.message_area.see(END)
        self.after_handle = self.after(100, self.dataready)

    def destroy(self):
        if self.after_handle:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_handle)
        super().destroy()

    def mouseClicked(self, e=None):
        self.remote.sendall(self.send_area.get().encode() + b'\r\n')
        self.send_area.delete(0, END)

    keyPressed = mouseClicked

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(MultichatClient.main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

---

**Simple_Client.pyw**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

"""Provide a GUI for easy interactions with Multichat servers.

This program is an example of a first attempt at implementing a client
for interacting with a Multichat server through purely graphical means."""

__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell <Noctis.Skytower@gmail.com>'
__date__ = '11 October 2012'
__version__ = 1, 0, 0

################################################################################

from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.constants import *
from safetkinter import *
import logging
import traceback
import _thread
import socket
import os
import traceback
import sys
import threadbox

################################################################################

class SimpleClient(Frame):

    "SimpleClient(master, **kw) -> SimpleClient instance"

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        "Create a GUI root and demonstrate the SimpleClient widget."
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Chat Client')
        root.minsize(675, 450)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.bind_all('<Control-Key-a>', cls.handle_control_a)
        frame = cls(root)
        frame.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        root.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def handle_control_a(event):
        "Process Ctrl-A commands by widget type."
        widget = event.widget
        if isinstance(widget, Text):
            widget.tag_add(SEL, 1.0, END + '-1c')
            return 'break'
        if isinstance(widget, Entry):
            widget.selection_range(0, END)
            return 'break'

    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        "Initialize the SimpleClient instance with the widgets it contains."
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Build Widgets
        self.output_area = ScrolledText(self, width=25, height=4, wrap=WORD)
        self.input_area = Entry(self)
        self.corner = Sizegrip(self)
        # Place Widgets
        self.output_area.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        self.input_area.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=EW)
        self.corner.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=SE)
        # Setup Widgets
        self.output_area['state'] = DISABLED
        self.input_area.bind('<Return>', self.send)
        self.after_idle(self.connect)

    def connect(self):
        "Try connecting to a server to begin chatting."
        self.connection = Connector(self, 'Chat Client').connection
        if self.connection is None:
            self._root().destroy()
        else:
            self.connection.setblocking(False)
            self.after_idle(self.update)

    def send(self, event):
        "Send a message across the connection from the given widget."
        self.connection.sendall(event.widget.get().encode() + b'\r\n')
        event.widget.delete(0, END)

    def update(self):
        "Update the output area with any incoming messages."
        self.output_area['state'] = NORMAL
        try:
            self.output_area.insert(END, self.connection.recv(1 << 12).decode())
        except socket.error:
            pass
        else:
            self.output_area.see(END)
        finally:
            self.output_area['state'] = DISABLED
        self.after(100, self.update)

################################################################################

def start_thread(function, *args, **kwargs):
    "Start a new thread of execution while logging any errors."
    _thread.start_new_thread(log_errors, (function, args, kwargs))

def log_errors(function, args=(), kwargs={}):
    "Execute a function with its arguments and log any exceptions."
    try:
        function(*args, **kwargs)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
    except:
        basename = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
        filename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0] + '.log'
        logging.basicConfig(filename=filename)
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())

################################################################################

class Dialog(Toplevel): # Copies tkinter.simpledialog.Dialog

    "Dialog(parent, title=None) -> Dialog instance"

    def __init__(self, parent, title=None):
        "Initialize a Dialog window that takes focus away from the parent."
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.withdraw()
        if parent.winfo_viewable():
            self.transient(parent)
        if title:
            self.title(title)
        self.parent = parent
        self.result = None
        body = Frame(self)
        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
        body.grid(sticky=NSEW, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.buttonbox()
        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.cancel)
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(parent.winfo_rootx() + 50,
                                          parent.winfo_rooty() + 50))
        self.deiconify()
        self.initial_focus.focus_set()
        try:
            self.wait_visibility()
        except tkinter.TclError:
            pass
        else:
            self.grab_set()
            self.wait_window(self)

    def destroy(self):
        "Destruct the Dialog window."
        self.initial_focus = None
        super().destroy()

    def body(self, master):
        "Create the body of this Dialog window."
        pass

    def buttonbox(self):
        "Create the standard buttons and Dialog bindings."
        box = Frame(self)
        w = Button(box, text='OK', width=10, command=self.ok, default=ACTIVE)
        w.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        w = Button(box, text='Cancel', width=10, command=self.cancel)
        w.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.ok)
        self.bind('<Escape>', self.cancel)
        box.grid()

    def ok(self, event=None):
        "Validate and apply the changes made by this Dialog."
        if not self.validate():
            self.initial_focus.focus_set()
            return
        self.withdraw()
        self.update_idletasks()
        try:
            self.apply()
        finally:
            self.cancel()

    def cancel(self, event=None):
        "Close the Dialong window and return to its parent."
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.parent.focus_set()
        self.destroy()

    def validate(self):
        "Verify that the Dialog is in a valid state."
        return True

    def apply(self):
        "Make any changes the Dialog wishes to accomplish."
        pass

################################################################################

class Connector(Dialog):

    "Connector(parent, title=None) -> Connector instance"

    def body(self, master):
        "Customize the Dialog window with some custom widgets."
        self.connection = None
        self.resizable(False, False)
        # Build Widgets
        self.prompt = Label(master, text='Enter server IP address:')
        self.address = Entry(master)
        # Place Widgets
        self.prompt.grid(sticky=W, padx=30, pady=2)
        self.address.grid(sticky=W, padx=30)

    def buttonbox(self):
        "Redefine the buttons at the bottom of the window."
        w = Button(self, text='Connect', width=10, command=self.ok,
                   default=ACTIVE)
        w.grid(sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.ok)
        self.bind('<Escape>', self.cancel)

    def validate(self):
        "Ask a Consumator to make a connection with the given address."
        c = Consumator(self, 'Chat Client', (self.address.get(), 8989))
        if c.connection is None:
            Message(self, icon=WARNING, type=OK, title='Warning',
                    message='Could not connect to address!').show()
            return False
        self.connection = c.connection
        return True

################################################################################

class Consumator(Dialog):

    "Consumator(parent, title, address) -> Consumator instance"

    def __init__(self, parent, title, address):
        "Initialize the Consumator with the server's address."
        self.server_address = address
        super().__init__(parent, title)

    def body(self, master):
        "Create the widgets for this Dialog and start the connection process."
        self.connection = None
        self.resizable(False, False)
        # Build Widgets
        self.message = Label(master, text='Trying to connect to address ...')
        self.progress = Progressbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        # Place Widgets
        self.message.grid(sticky=W, padx=10, pady=2)
        self.progress.grid(sticky=EW, padx=10, pady=2)
        # Setup Widgets
        self.progress.configure(mode='indeterminate', maximum=30)
        self.progress.start()
        result = []
        start_thread(self.connect, result)
        self.after_idle(self.poll, result)

    def buttonbox(self):
        "Cancel the creation of the buttons at the bottom of this Dialog."
        pass

    @threadbox.MetaBox.thread
    def connect(self, result):
        "Try connecting to the server address that was given."
        try:
            result.append(socket.create_connection(self.server_address, 10))
        except socket.timeout:
            result.append(None)

    def poll(self, result):
        "Find out if the any connection information is available yet."
        if result:
            self.connection = result[0]
            self.cancel()
        else:
            self.after(100, self.poll, result)

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_errors(SimpleClient.main)
```

---

**affinity.py**

```
"""Allow a simple way to ensure execution is confined to one thread.

This module defines the Affinity data type that runs code on a single thread.
An instance of the class will execute functions only on the thread that made
the object in the first place. The class is useful in a GUI's main loop."""

__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell <Noctis.Skytower@gmail.com>'
__date__ = '4 June 2012'
__version__ = 1, 0, 0

################################################################################

import sys
import _thread
import queue

################################################################################

def slots(names=''):
    "Sets the __slots__ variable in the calling context with private names."
    sys._getframe(1).f_locals['__slots__'] = \
        tuple('__' + name for name in names.replace(',', ' ').split())

################################################################################

class Affinity:

    "Affinity() -> Affinity instance"

    slots('thread, action')

    def __init__(self):
        "Initializes instance with thread identity and job queue."
        self.__thread = _thread.get_ident()
        self.__action = queue.Queue()

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        "Executes function on creating thread and returns result."
        if _thread.get_ident() == self.__thread:
            while not self.__action.empty():
                self.__action.get_nowait()()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        delegate = _Delegate(func, args, kwargs)
        self.__action.put_nowait(delegate)
        return delegate.value

################################################################################

class _Delegate:

    "_Delegate(func, args, kwargs) -> _Delegate instance"

    slots('func, args, kwargs, mutex, value, error')

    def __init__(self, func, args, kwargs):
        "Initializes instance from arguments and prepares to run."
        self.__func = func
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs
        self.__mutex = _thread.allocate_lock()
        self.__mutex.acquire()

    def __call__(self):
        "Executes code with arguments and allows value retrieval."
        try:
            self.__value = self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
            self.__error = False
        except:
            self.__value = sys.exc_info()[1]
            self.__error = True
        self.__mutex.release()

    @property
    def value(self):
        "Waits for value availability and raises or returns data."
        self.__mutex.acquire()
        if self.__error:
            raise self.__value
        return self.__value
```

---

**threadbox.py**

```
"""Provide a way to run instance methods on a single thread.

This module allows hierarchical classes to be cloned so that their instances
run on one thread. Method calls are automatically routed through a special
execution engine. This is helpful when building thread-safe GUI code."""

__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell <Noctis.Skytower@gmail.com>'
__date__ = '9 October 2012'
__version__ = 1, 0, 1

################################################################################

import functools
import affinity

################################################################################

class _object: __slots__ = '_MetaBox__exec', '__dict__'

################################################################################

class MetaBox(type):

    "MetaBox(name, bases, classdict, old=None) -> MetaBox instance"

    __REGISTRY = {object: _object}
    __SENTINEL = object()

    @classmethod
    def clone(cls, old, update=()):
        "Creates a class preferring thread affinity after update."
        classdict = dict(old.__dict__)
        classdict.update(update)
        return cls(old.__name__, old.__bases__, classdict, old)

    @classmethod
    def thread(cls, func):
        "Marks a function to be completely threaded when running."
        func.__thread = cls.__SENTINEL
        return func

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict, old=None):
        "Allocates space for a new class after altering its data."
        assert '__new__' not in classdict, '__new__ must not be defined!'
        assert '__slots__' not in classdict, '__slots__ must not be defined!'
        assert '__module__' in classdict, '__module__ must be defined!'
        valid = []
        for base in bases:
            if base in cls.__REGISTRY:
                valid.append(cls.__REGISTRY[base])
            elif base in cls.__REGISTRY.values():
                valid.append(base)
            else:
                valid.append(cls.clone(base))
        for key, value in classdict.items():
            if callable(value) and (not hasattr(value, '_MetaBox__thread') or
                                    value.__thread is not cls.__SENTINEL):
                classdict[key] = cls.__wrap(value)
        classdict.update({'__new__': cls.__new, '__slots__': (), '__module__':
                          '{}.{}'.format(__name__, classdict['__module__'])})
        cls.__REGISTRY[object() if old is None else old] = new = \
            super().__new__(cls, name, tuple(valid), classdict)
        return new

    def __init__(self, name, bases, classdict, old=None):
        "Initializes class instance while ignoring the old class."
        return super().__init__(name, bases, classdict)

    @staticmethod
    def __wrap(func):
        "Wraps a method so execution runs via an affinity engine."
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def box(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.__exec(func, self, *args, **kwargs)
        return box

    @classmethod
    def __new(meta, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        "Allocates space for instance and finds __exec attribute."
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        if 'master' in kwargs:
            self.__exec = kwargs['master'].__exec
        else:
            valid = tuple(meta.__REGISTRY.values())
            for value in args:
                if isinstance(value, valid):
                    self.__exec = value.__exec
                    break
            else:
                self.__exec = affinity.Affinity()
        return self
```

---

**safetkinter.py**

```
"""Register tkinter classes with threadbox for immediate usage.

This module clones several classes from the tkinter library for use with
threads. Instances from these new classes should run on whatever thread
the root was created on. Child classes inherit the parent's safety."""

__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell <Noctis.Skytower@gmail.com>'
__date__ = '4 June 2012'
__version__ = 1, 0, 0

################################################################################

import time
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.scrolledtext
import tkinter.ttk
import threadbox

################################################################################

tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()

@threadbox.MetaBox.thread
def mainloop(self):
    "Creates a synthetic main loop so that threads can still run."
    while True:
        try:
            self.update()
        except tkinter.TclError:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(tkinter._tkinter.getbusywaitinterval() / 1000)

threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Misc, {'mainloop': mainloop})

################################################################################

OldButton = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Button)
Canvas = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Canvas)
OldFrame = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Frame)
Menu = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Menu)
PhotoImage = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.PhotoImage)
Spinbox = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Spinbox)
StringVar = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.StringVar)
Text = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Text)
Tk = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Tk)
Toplevel = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.Toplevel)

################################################################################

Button = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Button)
Checkbutton = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Checkbutton)
Entry = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Entry)
Frame = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Frame)
Label = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Label)
Labelframe = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Labelframe)
Progressbar = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Progressbar)
Radiobutton = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Radiobutton)
Scale = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Scale)
Scrollbar = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar)
Sizegrip = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Sizegrip)
Treeview = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.ttk.Treeview)

################################################################################

Directory = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.filedialog.Directory)
Font = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.font.Font)
Message = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.messagebox.Message)
ScrolledText = threadbox.MetaBox.clone(tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText)
```

Comment: Thank's so much, I'm sorry for not being able to up vote you.