# I am making P2P chat program in python. The thrying to connect keeps looping how to fix

Tags: python-3.x

So im making this p2p chat program and ive made it so that if one persn disconnect it wil find a new host but whe i first start it up it loops trying to connect

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Trying to connect ...")
        time.sleep(randint(1,5))
        for peer in p2p.peers:
            try:
                client = Client(peer)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                sys.exit(0)
            except:
                pass
            if randint(1, 20) == 1:
                try:
                    server = Server()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    sys.exit(0)
                except:
                    print("Couldn't start the server ...")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```

i have the p2p set up just not the reconnect part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send/sync variable/text over LAN in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224933/send-sync-variable-text-over-lan-in-python-3)

Comment: This is no where near the same

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I a trying to make it so when someone disconnects it will try to connect to the server and it it cant it will make its own server